# Interacting with windbg using an API on a hosted server

Tags: windbg

I'm just getting started with debugging and I want to know if there's a way to use windbg that is on a hosted server. For example, I want to load the memory dumb onto windbg and interact with the program by sending API requests like "!analyze" to it and get the output as a response. Thanks!

Comment: You might get some ideas from https://www.wintellect.com/automating-analyzing-tons-of-minidump-files-with-windbg-and-powershell/

Comment: have you checked the remoting capabilities of windbg https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/remote-debugging-using-windbg

Comment: @blabb Yes I have. What I'm interested in is modifying the debugger engine as an API service and I'm not sure how to start as the docs don't seem beginner-friendly

Comment: I Have Difficulty understanding what an API service is  have you specifically tried the dbgsrv.exe , kdsrv.exe etc and rejected them as not suitable. or IDebugClient::StartProcessServer for that matter